# publish on facebook page from python cron job

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-3.x

I have a Facebook page dedicated to a web site with some statistical information and I want to publish some daily news on that page, like "today A equals to X and B is greater than Y, etc". What I want to publish is irrelevant anyway.

The problem is that I want this activity to be fully automated. I mean I do not want to click somewhere, I want this to be done from cron job. Solutions I found all depend on some per posting login related user activity.

Also, it is not quite clear to me if this is against FB policy.

So, the question is, how can I publish to Facebook page as Facebook page (not as myself) from cron job fully unattended.

My web-site is written in Django/Python3 and I know Python more or less, at least I know Python much better than PHP, so Python based solutions are preferred, but any are welcome of cource.

Comment: You can publish as a user using a GET request with the Facebook API , I don't know if it works for pages too, you can look into it here: https://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can create facebook posts using the Graph-API when you have a page access token with the `publish_actions` permission. Take a look at the 'Publishing' heading in the [page feed api documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/feed).

The easiest way to execute a django script periodically, is to create a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) and run it as a cron-job in linux or a scheduled task in windows. In this script you'll want to generate the message you want to post. Then you can do a `POST` request to `graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/feed/` to post the message to the page's feed. This can be done using e.g. [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html). The exact parameters and formats expected by the API can be found in [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/feed) (again under the 'Publishing' heading).